JSON Question - How Do I deserialise only certain elements?
I'm new to JSON and have got most of the way there to handing my API calls get.  One set of data returned comes back as this (field is called jsonResponse)...  My question is how do I only get a list of people when I deserialize?
{
    "objectIdFieldName": "OBJECTID",
    "globalIdFieldName": "",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "UserID",
            "alias": "USERID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
            "length": 20
        }
    ],
    "people": [
        {
            "person": {
                "UserID": "123456",
                "Username": "Sid Smith"
            }
        },
        {
            "person": {
                "UserID": "345678",
                "Username": "James Brown"
            }
        },
        {
            "person": {
                "UserID": "437658",
                "Username": "Peter Green"
            }
        }
    ]
}

My deserialize code in c# is as follows;
List<clsPerson> objPlanning = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<clsPerson>>(jsonResponse);

How do I limit the jsonResponse to only deliver back the 'people'?
Tried to turn the json Response into an array but that fails

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var jToken = jObject.GetValue("People");
var result =jToken.ToObject<List>();

and class structure qould be public class People{
public List Person {get;set;}
public People(){Person = new List();}
}
public class Person
{
public clsPerson person { get; set; }
}
public class clsPerson
{
public int UserID {get;set;}
public string UserName {get;set;}
}
